# NextJs getServerSideProps() never calls api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have created a nextjs page and inside the page, there is `getServerSideProps` that calls API to fetch data.

The problem is that `getServerSideProps` never calls API and returns a response error `403 Unauthorized`

nextjs is serving data from .next folder and returns a JSON response and instead of calling API it calls this URL `http://localhost:3000/_next/data/development/contacts.json`

This is my code

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import {
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardFooter,
  Container,
  Row,
  Button
} from "reactstrap"
import AdminLayout from "../components/layouts/AdminLayout"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import TablePagination from "../components/common/TablePagination"
import { fetchData } from "../api"
import { toast } from "react-toastify"
import { useSession } from "../context/SessionContext"
import ProtectPage from "../hocs/ProtectPage"
import { getContacts } from "../api/contacts"
import ContactsTable from "../components/contacts/ContactsTable"

const Contacts = ({ initialContacts, initialPagination, error }) => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(initialContacts)
  const [pagination, setPagination] = useState(initialPagination)

  const session = useSession()

  const handlePagination = async (page) => {
    fetchData({
      apiMethod: () => getContacts({ page }),
      callback: (res, error) => {
        if (error || !res) {
          toast("Error loading Contacts")
        } else {
          setContacts(res.data)
          setPagination(res.pagination)
        }
        session.loadingQueue.dequeue()
      }
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setContacts(initialContacts)
    setPagination(initialPagination)
  }, [initialContacts, initialPagination])

  return (
    <AdminLayout>
      {/* Page content */}
      <Container className="mt--7" fluid>
        <Row>
          <div className="col">
            <Card className="shadow">
              <CardHeader className="border-0">
                <Row className="justify-content-between w-100 m-0">
                  <h3 className="mb-0">Contacts</h3>
                </Row>
              </CardHeader>
              <ContactsTable contacts={contacts ?? []} />
              <CardFooter className="py-4">
                <TablePagination
                  {...pagination}
                  handlePagination={handlePagination}
                />
              </CardFooter>
            </Card>
          </div>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </AdminLayout>
  )
}

Contacts.propTypes = {
  initialContacts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  initialPagination: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  try {
    const contactsRes = await getContacts({})
    const { data: initialContacts, pagination: initialPagination } =
      contactsRes.data
    return {
      props: {
        initialContacts,
        initialPagination
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      props: {
        initialContacts: [],
        initialPagination: {},
        error: true
      }
    }
  }
}

export default ProtectPage(Contacts)
```

I tried to disable cache and nothing worked. still serving JSON files.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `getContacts` function? Also, it's expected that you'd see the data from `getServerSideProps` being served [from `_next/data/` as a JSON](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#when-does-getserversideprops-run), that's how `getServerSideProps` works internally. You won't see the API requests made by `getServerSideProps` in the browser because it runs on the server-side.

Comment: @juliomalves ```import axios from "axios"

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json"
  },
  withCredentials: true
})

export const getContacts = ({ page = 1, limit = 25 }) =>
  api.get("/contacts", { params: { page, limit } })```

Comment: @juliomalves You can see API requests made by `getServerSideProps` because it gets executed with client-side transitions using next/link

Comment: That's not the API requests made inside `getServerSideProps`, though. It's what's returned by `getServerSideProps` itself. The API requests made from inside `getServerSideProps` occur on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(contactsRes)` in `getServerSideProps`

Or

call your api from getServerSideProps (`await fetch(`your_path`)`)